# list mask in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using List control to display data in grouped order. The Store related to the list is loaded from the controller. here is my list view...

```
{
            id: 'teamListId',
            xtype: 'list',
            scrollable: true,
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="teamInfo">',
                                '<div class="teamName">{teamName}</div>',
                                    '<tpl if="isMyTeam === true">',
                                        '<div class="teamStatus teamStatusYes"></div>',
                                    '<tpl else>',
                                        '<div class="teamStatus teamStatusNo"></div>',
                                    '</tpl>',
                            '</div>'),
            store: 'Team',
            itemCls: 'teamListItem',
            action: 'teamListItemTap',
            grouped: true,
            flex : 1
        },
```

And here is the code to load the store

```
var teamStore = Ext.getStore('Team');
    teamStore.load({
        params: {
            id : 5,
            email : userId
        }
    });
```

It works fine most of the time BUT sometime loadmask doesn't get removed.. and keeps displaying it indefinitely even after store is loaded successfully. I used  unmask() and setMasked(false) of list but no luck so far..

Answer (score 0):

You can disable that loadmask by explicitly declaring this config in your list view:

`loadingText: false`